# Tasker: How to trigger recheck of state context?

Tags: tasker

As I understand it, when I set Tasker to execute a *tasks* in a profile that has a *state context* it executes the tasks **once** - when the state condition becomes true.

Is there a task command to make Tasker re-run the profile (in case the state condition still remains true, of course)?

*Background: I'm trying to make Tasker do some actions when net wifi closes, wait a while, then check if net connection is still closed to run the same actions again (effectively creating a loop that only ends when net connection becomes active).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a time context to your profile. There is a repeat option (check box).

Comment: Right, of course. Silly me, didn't realize you can actually uncheck the start and end times from the timer, leaving only the repeat option. This suits my needs perfectly. Though, still interested if there's a specific way to trigger the recheck by a command of some sort.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible very easily.

1. First make a profile for the context you want to trigger a check for (this is optional as you can select the same profile also)
2. Then make a task about for what you want to do if the context is still satisfied
3. Add "IF" condition to the task with variable %PACTIVE (for Profile Active) and put the name of the profile with the context you want to check in the 'Value'

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround: do a wait on entry to the task, and then for subsequent actions check if the current context is still active, using %PACTIVE. Example:

- profile "NoWiFiAtNightAndSleeping" (time context 23:00 till 08:00, no repeat; Display state off; WiFi connected)
- action 1: Wait 15 minutes
- action 2: WiFi set off `IF %PACTIVE ~R .*,NoWiFiAtNightAndSleeping,.*`

Answer (score 0):

One workaround for this seems to be to add a variable state check as additional context for the profile - then adjusting that variable to a different value and back triggers the check.

Seems like a rather silly way to do it, though. :)